Constructing a 2D Fenwick tree in O(n*m) time
It is known that you can construct a 1D Fenwick in linear time (Is it possible to build a Fenwick tree in O(n)? on Stack Overflow), but is it possible to extend this approach to efficiently construct a 2D Fenwick tree in O(n*m) time? I came up with the following algorithm but I can't find this result online anywhere so I'm not sure if it's correct.
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < values[i].size(); j++)
    {
        // zero indexed Fenwick tree.
        tree[i][j] += values[i][j];
        int jj = j | (j + 1);
        int ii = i | (i + 1);

        if (ii < values.size())
        {
            tree[ii][j] += tree[i][j];
        }

        if (jj < values[i].size())
        {
            tree[i][jj] += tree[i][j];
        }

        if (jj < values[i].size() && ii < values.size())
        {
            tree[ii][jj] -= tree[i][j];
        }
    }
}


Precisely what "cumulative sum" query do you need to perform on the array?
